# Group by date only not date time in Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to create an sql query inside a ruby on rails application.

I want to group the results by Date I have a column called created at it's a date-time column
I need to do grouping by date only not date-time any help?

The Query :

```
@trackings_per_post = Tracking.select("sum(1) as total, created_at").where(query).group("created_at")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `aliases`

```
@trackings_per_post = Tracking.select("sum(1) as total, to_char(created_at,'dd/MM/yyyy') as created_at_date").where(query).group("created_at_date")
```